# How to filter or delete specific data in pytorch efficiently

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor :

```
X=torch.Tensor([[ 0, 10, 10,  0,  5,  5,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 20,  0,  7,  7,  0,  0,  1,
          1,  0,  0, 17, 17,  0,  0, 13, 13,  0,  0,  4,  4,  0, 18, 18,  0, 12,
         12,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  6,  6,  0,  0,  5,  0, 15,  0,  0, 11,  0,  8,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0,
          4,  0, 20, 20,  0,  0,  0, 16, 16,  0,  0, 17, 17,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0,
         19, 19,  0]])#batch_size,size
```

I want to filter the nonzero data without changing the dimension of X.
For example:

```
X_filtered=torch.Tensor([[ 10, 10,   5,  5,   9, 20,    7,  7,    1,1,  17, 17, 13, 13,   4,  4, 18, 18,   12,12, ],
[  6,  6,    5,  15,   11,   8,  10, 4,   20, 20,   16, 16, 17, 17,  18,  19, 19, ]])
```

How can I achieve this most efficiently in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.
In you sample X_filtered tensor consist of two row of different length (20 and 17). Pytorch does not support this.